# Android - pass data from fragment to new java class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to pass an integer from a fragment to another java class however I keep getting an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("id", position);
Intent passInt = new Intent(view.getContext(), displayAccount.class);
passInt.putExtras(b);

startActivity(passInt);
startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), displayAccount.class));
```

Then in displayAccount.java:

```
 int id = (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id",0));
```

Comment: Why did you call `startActivity` two times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called double times `startActivity`. It will be work when you delete this line `startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), displayAccount.class));`. Because you didn't put bundle on this line, you just starting the activity. You already give intent with `startActivity(passInt);`